# Determining the information loss due to undersampling

Tags: statistics, image-classification, class-imbalance, sampling

I have an image dataset that I need to segment into directories (train, validation and test) using *ImageDataGenerator in TensorFlow/Keras*. The dataset is highly imbalanced:
[image]
For this I have decided to do the following *in the training set*: **under-sample the majority class and augment the minority class images**.
However, this under-sampling would result in the loss of information.

**Is there any way to quantify the extent of loss as a result of under-sampling the majority class, in terms of its share in the training set?**

Comment: Why would you undersample? That both changes the class frequencies to something unnatural and discards precious data.

Comment: The differences between the percentages of samples in the training set for each class were not TOO big. It was 75% for the majority class vs 85% for minority classes for an eventual 80-10-10 split. However, I had to drop the idea of under-sampling. Though I am still curious if there is a way to determine the extent of information loss due to under-sampling.

Answer (score -1):

refer article:
Entropy and improved k‐nearest neighbor search based under‐sampling (ENU) method to handle class overlap in imbalanced datasets